# How to fire an event when a radio-button (input) is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `type="radio"` inputs with the first option being checked by default. What I'd like to achieve is to fire a particular event if the second option (input) is checked. I've tried to do it though basic 'if/else' statement (detecting of a particular input has 'checked' attribute), but it doesn't work...

Here's the HTML part:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" id="sendnow" value="Send Now" checked>
<label for="sendnow" class="camp_lbl">Send Now</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" id="sendlater" value="Schedule Send">
<label id="zzz" for="sendlater" class="camp_lbl">Schedule Send</label>
```

And the CSS:

```css
#send_options_radio_selectors input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -o-opacity: 0;
}

#send_options_radio_selectors input[type="radio"] + label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 12%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 23px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  color: #505e6d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#send_options_radio_selectors input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -o-border-radius: 50px;
}

#send_options_radio_selectors input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #e16846;
}
```

Comment: `$('[name="radio-group"]').on('change', function(){ /* do something */ })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "listen" to the [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event. Then you can check if the specific `radio` is `:checked` using `.prop('checked)` (There are many ways to check this)

```js
$('[name="radio-group"]').on('change', function() {
  alert($('#sendlater').prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="radio-group" id="sendnow" value="Send Now" checked>
<label for="sendnow" class="camp_lbl">Send Now</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" id="sendlater" value="Schedule Send">
<label id="zzz" for="sendlater" class="camp_lbl">Schedule Send</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment:

Detect if the radio group value changes by listening to change:

```
$('[name="radio-group"]').on('change', function(){ /* do something */ })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture click event and after that check that radio button is checked or not like as :-

```
$("#sendnow").click(function()
{
     // Run every time when user click radio button 
     if( $(this).is(":checked") )
     {
         // Do what ever you want ;
         // Run only of radio button is checked
     }
});
```

You can use 
`$("input[type='radio']")` in place of `$("#sendnow")` to add it on every radio button .

Comment: a) That's already checked b) Then what if the user clicks it back?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney , Question is "How to fire an event when a radio-button (input) is checked?"  and **Click Event Binding** calls always but their inner if will be execute only radio button will be checked .

Comment: Clicking on the radio button and changing the value are not the same. You can change the value without clicking on the radio button itself (via keyboard or by clicking on a label). Furthermore, you could click on the radio button and not change the value (via `e.preventDefault();`)